# WordPress changing content:"" to content: &quot;

Tags: css

I'm trying to prevent container collapse using

```
section.main::after {
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display: table;
}
```

When I preview my page, the container has not opened up. Inspection shows the code being changed to

```
section.main::after {
    clear: both;
    content: &quot;
    display: table;
}
```

I've tried changing the "" to none, but that doesn't work either. Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: Where are you placing this CSS? Is it in a theme, the customizer, directly in post content?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that. I have to place it in the CSS box below the page content box.

Comment: That must be coming from a plugin or theme - there isn't a CSS box in the editor by default. You may have more luck if you build a child theme or find some other way to apply custom styles.

Comment: Thank you for the response. This is for work, so I'm limited in what I can do. I may have to ask our tech team to look at it.